# App terminating while switching ViewControllers in ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicontainerview

I have ContainerView and three buttons like tab.
While tap on button I want to switch the ViewControllers into the UIContainerView.
When tap on the button App gets crash, Here is my code.

```
- (void) cycleFromViewController: (UIViewController*) oldVC  toViewController: (UIViewController*) newVC{
  [oldVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
  [self addChildViewController:newVC];
    [self transitionFromViewController:oldVC toViewController:newVC duration:5 options:0 animations:^{
        newVC.view.frame = oldVC.view.frame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [oldVC removeFromParentViewController];
        [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        currentVC = newVC;
    }];

}

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Children view controllers <FirstViewController: 0x78e98580> and <ThirdViewController: 0x78e99a60> must have a common parent view controller when calling -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'
```

Comment: I think `[oldVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];` this cause the issue, after this line `oldVC` will not have a parent.Then `transitionFromViewController:oldC` cause crash.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: I have removed that line, again it get crash

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is pointing the problem

> 'Children view controllers  and
>    must have a common parent view
>   controller when calling -[UIViewController
>   transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'

Just make sure the VCs you are trying to switch belongs to the container as parent